# Java - Prime Factors - Tip to fix?

Tags: java, factors

I want to populate list with prime factors. What's wrong here?

```
public class factorClass {
    private ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    // constructor populates array of factors for a given number
    public factorClass(int factorThis) {
        int test = 2;
        while (factorThis > 1 ) { 
            if (factorThis % test == 0) { //factor found
                factors.add(test); //add factor to array
                factorThis = factorThis / test; //quotient is new number to factor
            } else {
                testFactor++;// try next integer
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, you tell us what's wrong :) What exactly happens when you try to run this code?

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? See [ask].

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are wrong:

1. You start by testing for factor 3, which means you'll never find 2 factors.
2. Your loop's condition - `testFactor > 1` - is wrong. `testFactor` keeps growing, so the loop will only terminate when `testFactor` overflows to a negative value. You should terminate when `NumberToFactor` becomes 1. i.e. change the condition to `NumberToFactor > 1`.

<strike>Oh, and there's another issue - `Factors` seems to be a constructor, but it appears inside a class of a different name - `factorClass`. The constructor must have the same name as the class.</strike>

Comment: More things wrong: violating java naming conventions, and of course: that class only has that private field, no getters. How is that supposed to work ...

Comment: ty will look into this